# Retrieve data from phalcon controller with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, phalcon

I'm following the tutorial from "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_qZOaGSEQE". I want to implement auto pagination in phalcon with jquery.
auto scroll is working properly without any error but the problem is I don't understand how to pass query data to jquery with phalcon.
that's why always 5 data is rendering continuously and its same data. I mean always rendering 1-5 again and again. 
**someone please help me...!** how could I retrieve data properly with auto pagination.

[ Controller ]

```
namespace Multiple\Frontend\Controllers;
use Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\Model as paginator;

public function postloaderAction()
 {
    $numberPage = $this->request->getPost("page", "int",1);
    $record_per_call = 5;
    $offset = ($numberPage - 1) * $record_per_call;
    $bloger = Blogs::find(array("limit" => array("number" => $record_per_call, "offset" => $offset), "order" => "datetime DESC"));
    foreach($bloger as $blog)
    {
        echo('<div> <h1><a href="blog/details/'.$blog->id.'">'.$blog->blog_title.'</a></h1><img src="uploads/blogs/'.$blog->blog_image.'"/></div>');
    }
 }

 public function indexAction()
 {
    if($this->request->isAjax())
    { 
        echo($this->view->getRender('blog', $this->postloader())); 
        return false;
    }
 }
```

[ 'Main Layout View / Jquery' ]

```
var page = 1;
mycontent(page);
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('.blogItems').height()) 
   {
    page++;
    mycontent(page);
   }
});
function mycontent(page)
{
    $('.loader_msg').html('Loading Expansion...');
    $.post('blog/postloader',{page:page}, function(data){
        if(data.trim().length == 0)
        {
          $('.loader_msg').html('No Data Found');  
        }
        $('.blogItems').append(data);
       // $('.animate').animate({scrollTop:$('.loading').offset().top}, 1000);
        $('.loader_msg').hide();  
    });
}
```

[ Blog View ]

```
<div class="blogItems">
    <p class="loader_msg"></p>
</div>
```

[ Output ]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is just because every time you are trying to get data with a limit in find will give you first 5 records every time, You have to give limit as well as offset to get next **n** results, and in Phalcon there is no direct way to give a limit and offset so you have to code in this way.

```
<?php
public function postloaderAction()
{
    $numberPage = $this->request->getPost("page", "int",1);
    $record_per_call = 5;
    $offset = ($numberPage - 1) * $record_per_call;
    $bloger = Blogs::find(array("limit" => array("number" => $record_per_call, "offset" => $offset), "order" => "datetime DESC"));
    foreach($bloger as $blog)
    {
        echo('<div> <h1><a href="blog/details/'.$blog->id.'">'.$blog->blog_title.'</a></h1><img src="uploads/blogs/'.$blog->blog_image.'"/></div>');
    }
}
```

This will surely work for you.

Comment: order by DECS its rendering only 5 data and not going 6,7,8 so on... still same as previous! if you please see "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_qZOaGSEQE" links query. actually i need query like the example with phalcon. Also its not getting stopped.

Comment: :@Akshay Singhai - Did you test the code plz? or did you watch the video link how they query?

Comment: I have tried for my db records code for that is 
    public function testAction()
    {
        print_r(json_encode(CityList::find(array("limit" => array("number" => 5, "offset" => 5)))));
        $this->view->disable();
    }   let me check for Order by and will let you know

Comment: if you will use Orderby also then it will first arrange the records based on order wise and then apply limit and offset so in this way you will get records but in reverse order, the same whatever you are getting by MySQL Query.

Comment: In your view page, you are sending data as POST parameters and in controller action, you are trying to get GET parameter, so you need to change getQuery to getPost

Comment: :@Akshay still something went wrong! now its rendering all of my data step by step but the problem is when its reached end of the data it should stop and show not found msg but its working as infinity loop! i update my full code whats my wrong? please!!

Comment: In attached image its first render 5 data and then shows 10 error cause: "i have 10 post in my db" and then its render 6-10 number data and then its repeating the errors. But its should stop with not found msg!

Comment: I'm also confusing about limit and record_per_call ! I want it show 5 data first time its render and  increase 1+(one by one) but every time its render 5 data.

Comment: Could you please do one thing, add $this-view->disable(); at the last line of postloaderAction

Comment: No! Is it required?

Comment: yes it is, because, by default in the end of the page, it redirect back to view page.

Comment: Still same problem! & nothing changed